# Can combination of ghee and honey be consumed?

Tags: food, ayurveda

I've heard that as per Ayurveda the combination of ghee and honey is considered as opposite food (Viruddha Ahara).
However, in the preparation of `banana rasayana` both honey and ghee are put together. `Banana Rasayana` being a traditional item how can it be wrong?

[Banana Rasayana](https://images.app.goo.gl/Rkbd4k7bqHt12ESq7)

Comment: Traditionally, Hindus use [panchamrita](https://spoonsofflavor.com/panchamrit-panchamrita-recipe/),  a combination of  **five nectars**,  i.e,, raw cow milk, yogurt, ghee, jaggery, and honey.  panchamrita will be consumed after puja by the devotees. So combination of ghee and honey is not bad.

Answer (score 3):

While preparing one of the Amlaki Rasayanas, mentioned in the Charaka Samhita, Ghee and honey are both used. So, it is not prohibited to consume the combination.

> By the following treatment [rasayana + the particular treatment
> described], the sages regained youthfulness and attained disease-free
> life of many hundreds of years, and endowed with the strength of
> physique, intellect and senses practised penance with utmost devotion:
> Fruits of- amalaka, haritaki  Or-  amalaka, bibhitaka  Or-  haritaki,
> bibhitaka  Or-  amalaka, haritaki, bibhitaka  +  bark of- palasa tree
> mud  One of the above sets of fruits should be wrapped in the palasa bark.  Then paste this with mud.  Then cook on charcoal, till
> well cooked. 447  Remove the seeds.  40Kg. of the remaining material
> [powder/pulp] [minus the bark and mud- discard these] should be
> collected.  Pound in a mortar with a pestle.  +  **curd  ghee  honey
> sesamum paste  tila oil  sugar  This should be taken on empty stomach
> by above method [listed in previous rasayanas** [[the
> {kutipaka/hut}]]].  After the course of treatment, one should be
> brought back to it’s [his] normal state by intake of gruel etc.  He
> should also be massaged and annointed with ghee and barley powder.
> “This is the limit of the use of the rasayana.”  Keeping in view the
> power of digestion, he should be given diet consisting of sastika rice
> added with ghee along with soup or milk for the period double of the
> same for treatment.  Thereafter he may move and eat according to
> pleasure

The above is being quoted from p 446 of the book [Charaka Samhita, Volume 1, Edited by Gabriel Van Loon](https://www.astrojyoti.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Charaka-Samhita-Acharya-Charaka.pdf)

And, there are other Rasayanas (promotive measures) too where Ghee and honey are used together (quoted from p 422).

> The following enema is best aphrodisiac and rasayana and alleviates
> dysuria, P and V:  **160gm. [each]- honey, ghee**  +  “equal quantity
> of”- hot water  +  20gm.- satapuspa [Peucedanum Graviolens Linn]  +
> 5gm.- rock salt -Si12#17.11

Also, as mentioned in [one comment under the question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42860/can-combination-of-ghee-and-honey-be-consumed#comment132544_42860), Panchamrita, which is widely used and consumed in Hinduism as auspicious, has both Ghee and honey in it.

> Dadhi Dugdham **Ghrita**inchava Sarkara Samyuktam **Madhu** |
> PanchAmritamidam Proktam Vidhayam Sarva Karmesu ||
>
> Curd, Cow's milk, Ghee, Sugar(sarkarA) and honey all mixed together
> is what constitutes the PanchAmrita. And it is prescribed to be used
> in all rituals (vidhayam sarvakarmesu).

Madhuparka, a sweet edible, both offered to deities as well as consumed by us is also prepared with both Ghee and honey.

Quoting from [Varaha Purana](https://www.astrojyoti.com/varahapurana-11.htm):

> *PREPARATION OF ‘MADHUPARK’*
>
> While describing the method of preparing Madhupark, Lord Varaha told
> Prithvi–“Madhupark” manifested from the right half of my body at the
> time when the process of creation began. This is the reason why it is
> so pure. Anybody who makes offering of Madhupark in the course of my
> worship,attains to my abode. **For the preparation of Madhupark honey,
> curd and ghee are mixed in equal proportion.** While preparing it
> sacred mantras in my praise should be constantly chanted. Giving some
> Madhupark to a dying man liberates his soul.”